# Pass the argv and argc to thread

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, parameter-passing

My program receives arguments from the user

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

and I have this function inside some thread (I can't change the function):

```
func(&argc, &argv);
```

As you can see, I need to call the thread, and inside this thread, to call `func` with those parameters.
I saw that there is a way to sent the thread multiple parameters with struct.

How does the struct suppose to look like? And how do I copy those parameters to the struct?

Comment: `struct Args { int argc; char *argv[]; };` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct arg_holder {
    int argc;
    char ** argv;
};

void * thread_caller(void * arg) {
    struct arg_holder arg_struct = *(struct arg_holder *)arg;
    free(arg);
    return func(arg_struct->argc, arg_struct->argv);
}
```

in `main`:

```
struct arg_holder * arg_struct = malloc(sizeof(*arg_struct));
arg_struct->argc = argc;
arg_struct->argv = argv;

pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_caller, arg_struct);
```

Comment: HI! thank ypou for the comment, but it givs me error when calling the fuc:  TCPserver.c:136:23: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct multiple_var’)
TCPserver.c:136:40: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct multiple_var’)

Comment: The first line of `thread_caller` should be: `struct arg_holder * arg_struct = (struct arg_holder *)arg;`

Comment: @DavidLaPorte I have copied the argument holder `struct` onto the stack intentionally. This way I can free the dynamic memory straight away and return the return value of the called function. This allows for tailcall compiler optimizations.

Comment: Ahh, right. So then the return statement should be `arg_struct.argc, arg_struct.argv` then, right? ('.' instead of '->')

Answer (score 1):

Thought to mention that, AFAIK, you can pass the command line arguments to the thread without copying them (i.e. - create a dedicated struct which contain them using malloc), due to the fact that the life time of the command line arguments is the life time of the process (main) they were provided to.

Cheers,

Guy.